# Should I fetch mysql data in bulks, or fetch as few as possible?

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm not so sure about the correct approach when using MySQL. When starting with a big website, I used to load articles with all their info using one function, `load_articles`. I loaded all articles that were supposed to be somehow displayed.

However often only some article info was used, for example only title, only image icon... So I created object oriented model, where `Article` uses MySQL to fetch the properties when needed, using `__get` and `ArrayAccess`. This results in higher number of queries in general, but reduces the ammount of data fetched from MySQL.

Of course, ideal approach would be to buffer the "data needed" and then send one query. But if this is too complicated for me, where should I aim?

1. Bulk fetch all data that may be needed and discard the unnecesary data - reducing the ammount of queries
2. Lazy-load the individual properties as they're needed when generating the page - fetching little data with many queries

If the second is the better, should I go as far as not fetching `SELECT *` and rather have multiple selects for individual properties, as they are needed?

Comment: What exactly are you optimizing? Is there anything that must be optimized or is it just a case of premature optimization based on nothing?

Comment: Primary reason is my curiosity - I'm not so sure how MySQL actually works. But I'm also sure my page could generate faster than in 2 seconds.

Comment: Right, then the real problem is much deeper. First step should be finding out why it takes 2 seconds. That means you are transferring a lot of data (megabytes or more) or MySQL is slow in finding the records you need which is usually due to suboptimal indexing or due to the fact that MySQL is badly configured. Sadly, PHP is rarely the bottleneck, and what you're trying to do is optimize something on PHP level by adjusting the logic. That won't yield the results you want, at least not to the point where you can feel it in your app.

Comment: I installed xdebug and now I'm trying to figure out, which part is taking most time.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `Answer totally depends on how your webpage is getting loaded& what are user requirements and what are your SLAs`.

suppose your page has 5 elements on it then your solutions will behave like below,

1. Fetch bulk data and store it locally and load it

   This is good approach when your user needs to see all data at once or something very    computational is required at user end. In this case also fetch only required attributes. never use `select * which is always worst`.
   Check your network bandwidth while transferring data and if possible `use CDN` if you have many images or static data.
2. Fetch only base data first and then according to user requirement fetch more data.

   This is good approach when your user generally wants to see only first section of webpage or rather he will be happy to see atleast first section on screen within 1 sec. 
   and slowly you can load/fetch more data as user scrolls down and performs some activity. 
   This ways you can save amount of memory needed on app. server and its cpu cycles processing bulk data. This approach also maintains the user by showing something very fast and continues to load.

This all was for page loading SLAs. Both options are suitable for different conditions(nowadays 2nd is more preferably used)

Coming to slow sql queries, you need to normalize the database and use proper indexes wherever required. use optimal sql queries to ensure only required data is fetched and with efficiency.

If you have something which cannot be normalized more and getting complex then you can look at nosql options.'

Applying these techniques efficiently will help you achieve your desired performance.
I hope I have cleared you confusion a bit.

Comment: You're answering a question "*How can I make my page load faster.*". That's not the question I asked... I'm looking for specific response regarding MySQL with good insight explaining what's happening on the background.

Comment: Right, I have explained the counterparts of your db access ways on your web application which should consider while querying database. It answers when to fetch in bulk and when to fetch in pieces which is the question I guess. sometimes only DB tuning is not enough.